# Correlated subquery "unknown column"

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I'm getting a `Unknown column 'sites.id' in 'where clause'` on the following query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as readers, AVG( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as avg_visits_pr
FROM sites
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
    FROM site_hits_unique
    WHERE site_id = sites.id
    AND date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY site_id, ip
    HAVING per_ip > 1
) AS returning_visitors
WHERE id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
```

I want to run the inner query for every sites.id (the example just uses a few IDs for testing purposes).

The correlated subquery is only one level deep, so I'm not quite sure why it's not getting `sites.id`.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason why from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html:

> Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries. They
>   are materialized in whole (evaluated to produce a result set) during
>   query execution, so they cannot be evaluated per row of the outer
>   query. Before MySQL 5.6.3, materialization takes place before
>   evaluation of the outer query. As of 5.6.3, the optimizer delays
>   materialization until the result is needed, which may permit
>   materialization to be avoided. See Section 8.2.1.18.3, “Optimizing
>   Derived Tables (Subqueries) in the FROM Clause”.

Although I still need to figure out how to rewrite my query to make it work the way I want it to. Is a function necessary / feasible here?

Comment: And from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-tables.html, "Derived tables cannot be correlated subqueries, or contain outer references or references to other tables of the same SELECT."

Comment: For the record, I believe I ended up using a stored procedure with a cursor loop to accomplish this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You should rewrite your query in a way like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as readers, AVG( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as avg_visits_pr
FROM sites
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip, site_id
    FROM site_hits_unique
    WHERE site_id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
    AND date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY site_id, ip
    HAVING per_ip > 1
) AS returning_visitors
on id=returning_visitors.site_id
WHERE id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
```

Comment: Yes, that is a possible route, however that is not optimized. I only want the inner query to focus on one `sites.id` at a time for performance reasons.